# What is the difference between using include? for Array and Hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to use the method `include?` to check whether a given item is present. Would anyone tell me what the difference is between using Array and using Hash?

For example:

```
a=[]; 
h={}
a.include? "abc"
h.include? "abc"
```

Is using Hash supposed to be faster and more memory consuming?

Comment: Different data structures for different uses.

Comment: For an array, `include?` steps through looking for `"abc"`.  For a hash, `include?` looks for a key `"abc"`, which it can find quickly (if present) because of the way hashes are implemented.

Comment: From the fact that array and hash are different, you should already know/be expecting that `include?` applies somewhat differently, at least. Your question as you spelled does not seem to make much sense. It seems what you really wanted to ask is whether you should use array or hash for your task.

Answer (score 0):

When confused, read the docs!

From: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-include-3F

> Hash#include? Returns true if the given key is present in hsh.

And from: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

> Array#include? Returns true if the given object is present in self (that is, if any element == object), otherwise returns false.

So `Hash#include?` looks for a matching key, not a value. And `Array#include?` searches for a matching object in the list.

---

In general, use an array when you have an *ordered* list of objects. And use a hash when you want a collection of *named* objects.

---

> Is using Hash supposed to be faster and more memory consuming in Ruby?

Don't worry about this for now. Really.

Technically, since hash keys can be large objects, a hash has potential to use more memory. But this can be tamed by using keys with a smaller footprint. Or even not using ruby at all would be a good idea if this is a major concern. In most cases, use the data structure that makes logical sense first, and optimize it later.

Comment: I don't understand your logic "since hash keys can be large objects, a hash has potential to use more memory." Doesn't that apply to array as well?

Comment: Nope. An array is indexed by an integer between zero and the total number of items. A hash is indexed by any object you want. If that object you use for a key is full of megabytes of data, you could be holding onto more memory than you need. Potentially. But like I said, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: From the OP's description, it looks like the OP is thinking of using a hash as is used in `Set`, that is to have arbitrary objects as keys, and perhaps only `true` for the values. On the other hand, array would have arbitrary objects as the members (not as indices). That doesn't make a hash any more memory consuming than an array (at least along the lines you mention).

Comment: It's hard to tell what the OP is really going for. There really isn't much to go on. Checking for presence is just one thing you would want to do with that data set.

Comment: But as I wrote, an arbitrary object can be put into an array, just as you can put an arbitrary object as a hash key. I don't see why you claim that a hash is more memory consuming than an array.